# How do you make the status bar show text instead of an icon in Swift (macOS)?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I was wondering if it was possible to make a status bar show text instead of it showing an icon in the status bar.
Though I don't think this'll be much help here's my code:

```
    let icon = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "statusIcon"))
    icon?.isTemplate = true // best for dark mode
    statusItem.image = icon
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
```

This is currently showing an image but how do I make it show text without making an image that has text in it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a NSTextField that you want show on status bar;
2. Create a custom NSView;
3. Add txt to your custom view;
4. Create statusItem and set the view, then done.

OC:

```
    #define DEFAULT_W 80
    #define DEFAULT_H 22
    NSTextField* txt      = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, DEFAULT_W, DEFAULT_H)];
    txt.stringValue = @"Hellow world!";

    mStatusBackgroundView = [[NSView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, DEFAULT_W, DEFAULT_H)];
    [mStatusBackgroundView addSubview:txt];

    mStatusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:DEFAULT_W];
    mStatusItem.view = mStatusBackgroundView;
```

Swift 3:

```
    let DEFAULT_W = 80
    let DEFAULT_H = 22
    let txt = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, CGFloat(DEFAULT_W), CGFloat(DEFAULT_H)))
    txt.stringValue = "Hellow world!"

    mStatusBackgroundView = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, CGFloat(DEFAULT_W), CGFloat(DEFAULT_H)))
    mStatusBackgroundView.addSubview(txt)

    mStatusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(DEFAULT_W))
    mStatusItem.view = mStatusBackgroundView;
```

Swift 5:

```
    let DEFAULT_W = 80
    let DEFAULT_H = 22
    let txt = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, CGFloat(DEFAULT_W), CGFloat(DEFAULT_H)))
    txt.stringValue = "Hellow world!"

    mStatusBackgroundView = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, CGFloat(DEFAULT_W), CGFloat(DEFAULT_H)))
    mStatusBackgroundView?.addSubview(txt)

    mStatusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(DEFAULT_W))
    mStatusItem?.button?.addSubview(txt)//or mStatusItem?.button?.title = "Hellow world!"
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
statusItem.button?.title = "My Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you not get a deprecation warning when setting the `image` property?

Read the [`NSStatusItem` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem) taking particular note of the `button` property: its description, type, and what that type inherits from...

If after this research you have an issue with your new design ask a new question, showing your new code, and someone will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: No, I actually didn't! I only found that it was deprecated when I looked it up online. I'm using Swift 3 though so that's probably it (but I'm still using Swift 3.2)

Comment: Its been deprecated since at least macOS 10.10 so it looks like the Swift compiler let you down there.

Comment: Well, `image` got deprecated in 10.14, so the warning doesn't appear if the deployment target is set to a lower value in @TheOkster's project.

Answer (score -1):

You use

```
NSStatusItem.title = ""
```

However, this is deprecated

Comment: Now it's deprecated, what should we use?